# What does a research proposal for PhD applications consist of?

Tags: phd, application, research-proposal

Am presently trying to get PhD admission in somewhat reputed universities in India. However most of their application ask for a research proposal about which I have no idea. **What does that mean and how should I write one in about 500 words?**

Any guidance will be very helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. You may want to take a look in [this close related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101491/writing-a-thesis-proposal). In addition, where the restriction of 500 words comes from?

Comment: "research proposal" aka the question you want to investigate / research .,..

Comment: @TheDoctor The application limits the number of words in research proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Propose a research topic, maybe using a hypothesis (it depends on you subject area): clearly identify what you want to find out.
2. Show why this a relevant piece of research for the rest of us.
3. Explain how you would attack the topic, what is your intended approach.
4. Show related research where others, if possible well known researchers, have done their research.

During your research, all these elements could change, however, if you lack of an idea before, it will be hard.